# blockproc between two images

Tags: matlab, block, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to compute a block function between image 1 and 2. In the example below, I'm trying to multiply each block of image 1 with the top left block of image 2

```
Blocksize = 3;

fun = @(block) block.data .* im2(1:Blocksize, 1:Blocksize);
im3 = blockproc(im1,[Blocksize Blocksize],fun, 'TrimBorder', 1);
```

I keep getting the `Matrix dimensions must agree` error, and I don't know why. To my understanding both blocks are 3x3.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes when MATALB tries to evaluate the function for the corner blocks. If you go into the `blockproc` function, you can observe that the error occurs because the `getBlock` function returns a `3x1` block (?). Therefore, you should set `PadPartialBlocks` to true.

```
Blocksize = 3;

fun = @(block) block.data .* im2(1:Blocksize, 1:Blocksize);
im3 = blockproc(im1,[Blocksize Blocksize],fun, 'PadPartialBlocks',1,'TrimBorder', 1);
```

Also, you mention that you want to multiply with the top right block but in fact you are accessing the top left block.

Comment: That sounds good, right vs. left was a typo, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just with indexing:

```
im3 = im1.*im2(mod(0:size(im1,1)-1,BlockSize)+1, mod(0:size(im1,2)-1,BlockSize)+1);
```